# Mysql cursor throwing error while giving value dynmicalliy

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am declaring mysql cursor with select statement and passing database name with variable but getting error. I am using python 2.7 and mysql version 5.6
with MySQLdb package.

I have tried all method provided over stack over flow.
 cur.execute("select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db=%s and U.host= '%' order by user;",[db])

cur.execute("select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db=%s and U.host= '%' order by user;",db)

cur.execute("select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db=%s and U.host= '%' order by user;",(db))

cur.execute("select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db=%s and U.host= '%' order by user;",db)

````
MySQLdb.connect(host='##############',user='#####,passwd='###',db='mysql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    db="mysql"
    query = """select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db=%s and U.host= '%' order by user;"""
    cur.execute(query, (db))```

expecting values from tables but getting error.
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 104
````

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
and U.host= '%'
```

the 's' is missing, you want

```
and U.host= '%s'
```

Also note that your query requires two arguments (you're only passing one):

```
" D.db=%s and U.host= '%s'"
```

so you want:

```
cur.execute(query, (db, host))
```

Also and FWIW, `(db)` doesn't create a tuple, you'd need `(db,)` (with a comma). Actually it's the comma that creates a tuple, not the parens (except for the empty tuple of course...), here you only need the parens to force evaluation of the expression as a tuple since you're creating the tuple in the function's arguments list.

Answer (score -1):

```
Below one worked for me.

db='mysql'
query = "select distinct U.user,U.password,U.host from user U,db D where U.user=D.user and D.db='{}' and U.host= '%' order by user;".format(db)
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: Please do NOT advise mis-using db-api in a way that compromise security (https://bobby-tables.com/ for more)

Comment: Note to reviewers: the VLQ queue is NOT for judging the technical merits of an answer. If you think that this answer is wrong, you should downvote and comment (not vote to delete).

Comment: [20k+ users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) have the privilege of voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower, for example of voting to delete answers that would compromise security. In SO sister sites like Super User, Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux Stack Exchange this is a real issue. This is following the recommendations of @EJoshusS to comment (which I did) and not vote to delete (I didn't vote to delete).